# Why is it a bad idea to use the same field for loop control variables in different methods of a class?

Tags: java, for-loop, scope

Question from a practice final for Intro to Java Class:

> Why is it a bad idea to use the same field for loop control variables in different methods of a class?
>
> A. Because if a method is called from the body of the loop, it may reset the value of the variable used to control that loop
>
> B. Because it’s not a good style to use the same names for variables in different methods
>
> C. Because it wastes memory
>
> D. Because local variables can be kept in CPU registers, and the loop will run faster

The answer is A, but I do not really understand the question in the first place.  How does the the variable in the loop affect the second method?  And then wouldn't this hold for outside of a loop in a normal method call?  If someone could provide an example in code that would be great.

Comment: Obviously, it says so in the first sentence. There's nothing wrong with questions from school as long as the OP doesn't *just* dump a question on us. dardeshna gave his/her thoughts, which is all we ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By "same field", I presume the question means the exact same variable, not two different variables with the same name. Like so:

```
class X {
    int i;

    void foo() {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            bar();
        }
    }

    void bar() {
        for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
            System.out.println("foobar");
        }
    }
}
```

Code like this intends to loop 200 times total, but reusing `i` in both methods causes one loop to interfere with the other.

To be fair, the question is not worded very well. Code is much clearer than prose.

Comment: That's what I think it means too. But as a ten year Java pro I have never heard of anybody trying to do this.

Comment: Agreed. This is the kind of mistake I saw 20 years ago in simpler languages like BASIC where global variables were common. I don't see people make this kind of mistake in Java.

Comment: People prefer to get into trouble with `static` fields ;)

Answer (score 0):

For example. If you call countToTen and someone reset the counter you will have problems

```
public class FooExample{

    private int countedNumbers = 0;

    public void countToTen(){

        resetCounter();

        while(countedNumbers <= 10){
            System.out.println("Record number " + countedNumbers);
            countedNumbers++;
        } 
    }

    public void resetCounter(){
        countedNumbers = 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't say "the same variable", it says "the same *field*".  "Field" is another name for an *instance* variable.  (a.k.a., "member variable").

IMO, the answer is E:  Good programming style/practice is all about making it easier for other programmers to read your code, and the best way to do that is, don't surprise them.  In this case, don't surprise them by using a field to store information that is not part of the *state* of the object.  (Loop control variables are virtually *never* part of an object's state)

But A is a good answer too.  (Don't surprise yourself by making the mistake that it describes.)  And also, C *might* be a good answer in some performance-critical application, and answer D *might* be valid for some JVM implementation.

The only answer that's unconditionally wrong is B because there's nothing inherently wrong with giving different variables the same name if the name succinctly describes what their values mean.